# How to run a Java program using ProcessBuilder inside the other Java program. (with -cp and -Xbootclasspath commands)

Tags: java, process, java-5

Here is my code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String directory = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "cache";
        System.out.println(directory); // "/Users/byron1st/cache"
        try{
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java",
                    "-cp", directory,
                    "-Xbootclasspath/p:", directory,
                    "framework.PFSystemMain");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            builder.redirectOutput(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/output.txt"));
            builder.start();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This program builds a process to run a java program with -cp and -Xbootclasspath commands. Classes of the target program are in `/Users/byron1st/cache` folder.

[image]

What I want to do is to run `java -cp /Users/byron1st/cache -Xbootclasspath/p: /Users/byron1st/cache framework.PFSystemMain`

(The reason that I use `Xbootclasspath/p:` is that I have some instrumented classes to log.)

This code cannot run the process and just produce an error message meaning "It cannot find or load a default class called '.Users.byron1st.cache'". (I'm sorry for showing the error message directly because it is written in Korean.)

What is wrong with my code to use ProcessBuilder?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem. It is because of '`Xbootclasspath/p:`'.
I changed my code like below:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java",
                "-cp", directory,
                "-Xbootclasspath/p:" + directory,
                "framework.PFSystemMain");
```

In fact, I thought -Xbootclasspath/p: and its directory path are separate arguments for processbuilder, but it is not.